# Setting password for Redis Ruby Client

Tags: ruby, redis, redis-cluster

I am trying to test my ***cluster*** using [these ruby clients](https://github.com/antirez/redis-rb-cluster) by the creator of Redis itself. But I constantly get the following error:

> *error Can't reach a single startup node. NOAUTH Authentication required*

I have tried:

```rb
startup_nodes = [
        {:host => "redis-cluster-service", :port => 6379, :password => 'pass'}
    ]

startup_nodes = [
        {:host => "redis-cluster-service", :port => 6379, password: 'pass'}
    ]

RedisCluster.new(startup_nodes,32,:timeout => 0.1,:password => 'pass')
RedisCluster.new(startup_nodes,32,:timeout => 0.1, password: 'pass')
RedisCluster.new(startup_nodes,32,:timeout => 0.1,:auth_pass => 'pass')=
```

None of these variations seem to work. There is no error with the password I am using. I can log into the ***redis-cli*** using the same password.

Any help with regards to this would be of great help.

Thank you.

Comment: It seems like this gem doesn't support passing password to get redis connection https://github.com/antirez/redis-rb-cluster/blob/master/cluster.rb#L43

Comment: I just figured it out. The example code that is there in the repo is `example.rb` and `consistency-test.rb` use an old way of creating a client and it doesn't work. But the one you have linked uses the correct one and we can pass a password to it. See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example is of the old client code,.
After hours of toil I found that the following works:

```rb
rc = Redis.new(cluster: startup_nodes,:timeout => 0.1, replica: true, password: 'PASSWORD')
```

Would be nice if the docs were updated. I had created an [issue on the github page](https://github.com/antirez/redis-rb-cluster/issues/14) for the examples in the offcial Redis docs.

Hopefully it will get updated.